# What is this Windows (10) screen snipping application and how do I disable it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts, hotkeys, screenshot

It gets activated with this hotkey: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

I want to disable it (or at least change the hotkey) since I need that same hotkey for Winsplit.

[image]

Comment: This does not happen on my Windows 10 version 1909 installation.  Whatever application that is cannot be identified based on the information you have provided.  What is clear is it isn't the built-in application.

Comment: This must be some installed application. Use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag the bull's eye icon over this window. This will identify the executable.

Comment: Snip and Sketch wants Win Logo Key + Shift + S to launch it and that works here. Ctrl-Alt-A does not launch (as Ramhound noted).  Do you have Auto Hot Key running?  Accessibility Functions running?  Or as harrymc noted another application conflicting. By the way, it is a very useful application, so just figure out how to control it.